# Why are some football clubs known as Wanderers?

Tags: etymology, sports

Why are Bolton Wanderers, Wolverhampton Wanderers, Wycombe Wanderers etc so known?

The OED seems to be silent on the matter, so I searched elsewhere on line. The following answer came up. Does it appear to be a satisfactory answer in other people's opinion? Can anyone from Bolton or Wolverhampton supply any further information?

> Q. Why do football teams often use the word 'Wanderers' in their names
>
> A. As we all know wanderers are people who roam around from place to
> place. The first winners of the FA Cup, in 1872, were called simply
> the Wanderers, a name the club adopted in 1864 after moving from east
> London to Battersea Park in south London. But the name also conveys
> the rather romantic sense of a group of travelling gentlemen who play
> for pleasure rather than to win - a very English sentiment,
> particularly in the late 19th century when most clubs were formed. So
> we have Wolverhampton Wanderers, Wycombe Wanderers and Bolton
> Wanderers.
> <sub>[The AnswerBank](https://www.theanswerbank.co.uk/Phrases-and-Sayings/article/some-football-club-names-are-pretty-obvious-but-why-leyton-orient/)</sub>

Comment: I didn't know you guys played football, too.

Comment: @LittleEva you'd probably know it as soccer. There's a question or 2 in the use of "football" across the English-speaking world I'm sure.

Comment: @ChrisH - Just teasing ya'll. I love both versions of "football." ;-)

Comment: @LittleEva, I must be a little slow on the uptake in the middle of the night. :)

Comment: Imitation is the sincerest form of flattery. The early Wanderers' Championship likely inspires the other clubs.

Comment: @LittleEva When you say you love both forms of football, I am assuming you mean the kind the Wanderers play, and Rugby football.

Comment: @ScotM I think you may have hit upon something there. You may care to look and the Wiki site on the 1872 Wanderers and possibly post it as an answer.

Comment: @WS2, you mean the Wanderers play both kinds of football, rugby union football, and rugby league football?

Comment: @WS2 - exactly!

Comment: May I point out, *Little Eva*, that because some Soviet-era football [soccer] clubs were based around various industries, there's still a football club in Russia called Moscow Locomotiv [Футбо́льный клуб "Локомоти́в" Москва́]!

Comment: @BrianHooper The Wanderers were an Association Football team who won the F.A.Cup in 1872.

Comment: @DavidGarner I remember Moscow Dynamo. Is that the same sort of thing? They used to be a great side.

Comment: Yes, pretty sure they were backed by the power generation union.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [blog entry](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2016/01/football-team-names/) from the Oxford Dictionaries addressing English football club names. It's newer than the original question. The following explanation is offered for the clubs named *Wanderers* early on.

> The names Wanderers, as in Wolverhampton and Dundee, and Rovers, as in Bristol and Raith, were adopted by teams without a permanent home ground. [- ODO Blog](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2016/01/football-team-names/)

Everyone named Wanderers who adapted the name later on is as likely as suggested in the comments on the imitation train.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you. I didn't realise that Dundee were called Wanderers, though.

Comment: Those guys: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dundee_Wanderers_F.C. disbanded a long time ago.

Answer (score -1):

Wolverhampton Wanderers started out as St Lukes Boys as the played from St Lukes Church,  they outgrew  their ground and moved to a pitch in Wanderers Avenue in Wolverhampton and adopted the name Wolverhampton Wanderers

Comment: Do you have any historical references to back this up? Are you sure that it wasn't the other way round  and  Wanderers Avenue was named after the football club?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolverhampton_Wanderers_F.C.) has that St Luke's FC was founded in 1877, and merged with the football section of a local cricket club called Blakenhall Wanderers to form Wolverhampton Wanderers in August 1879. Quite why Blakenhall Wanderers were called that is not specified.